# How do I loop and stop at the next item in the array which matches a value? (Google Sheets App Script)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm working on my first Google Script Project, and need advice on how to get unblocked

Context:

1. I'm building a way to **rotate trash duty** every Saturday.
2. Users can **skip their turn by clicking a button**, which automatically assigns the next user in the list
3. Users can **change their status to "Vacation"**, which should auto-skip them when determining who to assign next

Somehow, I got 1 and 2 working-- but I'm struggling with #3.

[See screenshot of how it currently works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6xry.png)

---

This is what I currently have. Any small tips or suggestions would be amazing! Thank you all so much.

```
var housemates = [
["User 1","✅ Active",false],
["User 2","⛔ Vacation",false],
["User 3","⛔ Vacation",true],
["User 4","✅ Active",false],
["User 5","✅ Active",false],
["User 6","✅ Active",false]`
]
```

```
// 0. Gets full list of all users
function getUsers(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var range = sheet.getRangeByName("housemates");
  var values = range.getValues();

  return values;
}

// 1. Finds Current Assignee
function getCurrentUser(){
  var values = getUsers(); //full list
  const columnIndex = 2; // INDEX OF COLUMN FOR COMPARISON CELL
  const matchText = true;

  let currentUser = values.findIndex(row => row[columnIndex] === matchText);

  return currentUser;
}

//2. Calculates Next Assignee
function getNextUser(){
  var values = getUsers(); //unfiltered list of users
  var currentUser = getCurrentUser(); //current assignee

   if (currentUser < values.length - 1){
    var nextUser = currentUser + 1;
  }

  else {
     var nextUser = 0;
  }

  return nextUser;
}

//3. OnClick Event
function onSubmit() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var range = sheet.getRangeByName("housemates");
  var values = getUsers(); //unfiltered list of users
  var currentUser = getCurrentUser(); //current assignee
  var nextUser = getNextUser(); //next assignee

  values.forEach(function (row, index) {
    if(index != nextUser) {
      values[index][2] = false;
    }  
    else{
      values[index][2] = true;
    }
  });
  range.setValues(values);
  }

// 4. Confirmation Modal
function confirm() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRangeByName("housemates");
  var values = range.getValues();

  const currentUser = getCurrentUser();
  const currentUserName = values[currentUser][0];
  
  const nextUser = getNextUser(); //next assignee
  const nextUserName = values[nextUser][0];

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  const title = `⚠️ Are you sure?`;
  const description = `By continuing, ` + nextUserName + ` will be assigned.`;
  var response = ui.alert(title, description, ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  if (response == ui.Button.YES){
    onSubmit();
  }

  else if (response == ui.Button.NO){
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is your code for #3 so we can help you fix it?

Comment: Put the code that iterates `currentUser` in a `while` loop that checks whether the current user's status is Vacation. If not, it breaks out of the loop.